# Installing Multiple Python Distributions, Windows

Tags: python

I am using PythonXY (2.7, 32-bit) and the official Python (2.7, 32-bit).

Normally it is recommended to install according to python version, example `C:\python27`. But since they are both `python27`, can I arbitrarily change the base name (example `C:\pythonxy27`)?

When using python *extras* like **pylauncher**, or when utilizing the **setuptools** *user-site*, will they automatically recognize my custom installation sites (they will easily differentiate `C:\python27` and `C:\python33`), or will both installations compete for the `python27` *namespace*. (specifically when installing 3rd party packages to *user-site*, which normally locates as such **\APPDATA\Python\PythonVer**)

Comment: It depends when you installed it. If you specified it to be installed in `C:\somewhere\Python27` it would still work well..

Comment: if you told the installer where to install, then that location is (hopefully) in the registry, and additional tools should be able to read and understand that. Don't change the directory name once you've already installed, you'll just screw everything up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as setuptools/distribute are concerned, the python installer will handle custom locations for you. As long as you don't move that directory, all should be fine.

## As for **Pylauncher**:

Things are not quite so clean. Pylauncher has simple configuration/call-parameters (for shebang lines in particular), that can handle version/platform selection quite well (2.7 vs 3.3, and 32bit vs 64bit).

As for the scenario in question (two different deployments where both are based on 32bit Python 2.7), pylauncher will attempt to guess which installation you wanted. If it is picking the wrong installation, there is some debugging information you can review to tune pylauncher's selection.

> If an environment variable `PYLAUNCH_DEBUG` is set (to any value), the
>   launcher will print diagnostic information

It does not seem like there is a portable way to configure this, and will have to be done per-system (once you have your installations configured, YOU CAN set an alias that will be recognized on the shebang line)

---

## Virtualenv and friends

I have also found (after struggling with pylauncher focused solutions), virtualenv addresses many of the *deployment isolation* hurdles. At the time of posting, working with virtualenv was not nearly as intuitive (on Windows) as compared to a linux shell environment. But I have discovered support packages like **virtualenvwrapper** which handle a lot of the ugly batch file interfaces very nicely.

## Final Notes

Originally, I was also handling python globally with admin accounts. Forcing myself to stay within my user home directory (C:/Users/**username**), utilizing python **user-site** configurations, and making optimum use of ipython: have all given me a much better interactive command-line experience.